# Why are my strings changing unintentionally?

Tags: c++

I'm making a simple caesar cipher decryption program in C. It takes a string input (stored in text) and should print every possible shift in letters.

If I were to give ABC as input, it should print:

```
ABC
BCD
CDE
DEF
EFG
...
```

However, it actually prints:

```
ABC
BCD
DEF
GHI
KLM
PQR
VWX
CDE
KLM
TUV
...
```

The code is:

```
int main(void)
{
    // prompt for plaintext
    string text = GetString();
    string newtext = text;
    for (int k = 0; k < 26; k++)
    {
        for (int i = 0, n = strlen(text); i < n; i++)
        {
            if (text[i] >= 'A' && text[i] <= 'Z')
            {
                newtext[i] = (text[i] - 'A' + k) % 26 + ('A');
            }
            else if (text[i] >= 'a' && text[i] <= 'z')
            {
                newtext[i] = (text[i] - 'a' + k) % 26 + ('a');
            }
        }
        printf("%s\n", newtext);
        printf("%s\n", text);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I put printf("%s\n", text); only to debug, and I found that the text string is changing every iteration of the loop, instead of only the newtext string.

Also, I'm including some header files already.

Why is text changing?

Comment: Is that supposed to be [std::]string from *C++*? If so please fix the tags. If not, provide the relevant definition.

Comment: because `string newtext = text;` this make alias. try change to  `string newtext = calloc(1, strlen(text)+1);`

Comment: Please show your `GetString`, it's probably the source of your problem.

Comment: Eh, I'm a little sleepy and slightly overwhelmed, sorry, but ok:
It's C99, I'm using string.h and cs50.h. The latter has the function GetString(). I'll try what BLUEPIXY suggested first.

Comment: I can't see how GetString() is written because it's in a library not made by me. calloc worked, but I had to edit the code a bit to handle non-letter characters. So... everytime I want to copy a string to another variable I have to iterate through every character?

Comment: or `+ k` change to `+ 1`(1:shift size)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have defined `string` type as:

```
typdef char * string;
```

In that case, change

```
string newtext = text;    /// Here, both point to same memory
```

to

```
string newtext = strdup(text);
```